# Send string from android to visual basic 2010

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, wifi, android-wifi

I want to send a string from Android to my PC (visual basic 2010) i try this one but it's not working. Please anyone help me..

I get my Android Code from : 
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

And its Look Like :

```
package com.zelacroix.bukumenu;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
public class TesKirim extends Activity {

        private EditText serverIp;

        private Button connectPhones;

        private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.1.2";

        private boolean connected = false;

        private Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.teskirim);

            serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
            connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);

            connectPhones.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!connected) {
                        serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
                        if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                            Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                               "masuk if",  
                                               10)
                                .show();
                            cThread.start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = 
                        InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr , 10000);
                    connected = true;
                    while (connected) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                            PrintWriter out = 
                                new PrintWriter(
                                    new BufferedWriter(
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                            socket.getOutputStream())), 
                                    true);

                                // where you issue the commands
                                out.println("Hey Server!");
                                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                        }
                    }
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                    connected = false;
                }
            }
        };
};
```

my Visual Basic is using UDP method.. And its Look Like :

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim udp_Client As New UdpClient(10000)

            Dim remoteIpEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)

            Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = udp_Client.Receive(remoteIpEndPoint)
            Dim returnData As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(returnData.ToString)
            udp_Client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please I really2 need to comunicate them..

Comment: Whats the problem You are facing?

Comment: Where is a issue? Your android doesn't send data? Or maybe your VB doesn't receive it? maybe something is wrong with string encoding?
Have you checked using Wireshark if string was send?

Comment: first, my problem.. my Android just running till Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting..."); so i checked in DDMS Log. Then the code cannot proccess further :( whats wrong is it? i got error something says like family doesn't support.

Comment: If you are seeing an error in logcat, please post the logcat output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is caused since you are mixing TCP and UDP communication. The Visual basic app is expecting to receive data over UDP and the Android App is sending over TCP.   I created the Android and VB projects from your code and called following UDP send function from the android app and the communication works fine. The string from Android appears correctly in the listbox in the VB app. Try using UDP sockets from your android app as follows:

```
private void udp_send(String serverIpAddress) throws IOException
        {
            String messageStr="Hello Android!";
            int server_port = 10000;
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            int msg_length=messageStr.length();
            byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length,local,server_port);
            s.send(p);
        }
```

[i tried this code on an android simulator and the VB app running on the same machine. in case you are trying accross different machines and still face problems with the above code, make sure that the udp traffic for the port 10000 is not stopped by some firewall. You can give the detailed exception log from the Android app for us to better understand the problem if necessary]

Comment: wow!! bingo!! thank you nilesh pawar! your code it's work! big thanks!! since i'm a newbie, i don't know that if i create SOCKET object it is TCP.. thank you so much.. if i want my Android to receive something from VB using UDP then what should i do? do you have any reference? thank you so much!!

Comment: You can use the Datagram sockets as follows to receive UDP data in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818284/udp-server-doesnt-accept-calls-from-outside      Network communication related code across client-servers made in different languages can be a bit bogging down to the newcomer particularly since different languages have different representation for data like Strings etc. Best way is to debug systematically. The Development systems these days give very detailed errors and simply copy-pasting the error code in Google would return a huge amount of info as to how to fix it.

Comment: Just as a question, isn't TCP as a rule generally better than UDP (at least more reliable?)

Comment: "better" is a context sensitive term . if u need reliabilty then TCP is good. For certain type of data like live streaming video and audio, a few packet losses are acceptible and UDP performs much better than TCP in this case. In case of Michael, yes I think he would benefit from TCP since he is passing strings and may be expecting  them to reach reliably.

Comment: woahhh.. you are a big help Nilesh!! thank you so much hehe.. yeah i'm still newbie n need much more to learn @@.. sometimes got confused >"<.. thanks for your explanation so far ^^..

Comment: hmmm yeah.. i think i would change to use TCP to ensure that string sent is correct.. thank for your advice Big Endian :)

Comment: Yeah so far i success to change the system using TCP.. thanks for all the help..now i'm facing a trouble in web service.. hope it will solved soon :)